# React native fetch data from API and displaying

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hi i'm fairly new to react native and im trying to fetch data from an `API`, then display them as such in my `movies.js` . But it gives me the error `undefined is not a function(near'..data,map..')`. I thought of mapping the `json` data to an array `movieComponent`. The `console.log(data)` shows the data properly as it should in `json` format. Not sure what i'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance!
**App.JS**

```
export default function App() {

const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
console.log(data);

useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=superman&apikey=28f4dae9')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, []);

const movieComponent = data.map(movie => <Movies key={movie.imdbID} moviee={movie}/> )
console.log(movieComponent);
  return (
<SafeAreaView>
    <ScrollView className="App">
      <Header />
      {movieComponent}
    </ScrollView>
</SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

**Movies.js**

```
import React from "react"
import { Image , Text , View} from "react-native"

function Movies(props) {
    return (
        <View>
            <Image source={{uri: props.movies.Poster}} 
        style={{width: 300, height: 300}} /> 
            <Text>Title: {props.movies.Title}</Text>
            <Text>Year: {props.movies.Year}</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

export default Movies
```

Comment: Your `setData(json)` might be undefined or not an array please check what's in it?

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani I did console.log(setData), I am getting [Function bound dispatchAction], is it not supposed to be like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

API response is object `{ Search: [] }` and not an array.

Change from

```
.then((json) => setData(json))
```

To

```
.then((json) => setData(json ? json.Search : []))
```

Alse issue-2. There is typo `moviee={movie}`

Answer (score 0):

data may have some values other than array like `undefined`, try this:

```
export default function App() {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  console.log(data);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=superman&apikey=28f4dae9")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, []);

  const movieComponent =
    data.length &&
    data.map((movie) => <Movies key={movie.imdbID} moviee={movie} />);
    
  console.log(movieComponent);
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <ScrollView className="App">
        <Header />
        {movieComponent}
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i suggest to use FlatList because of better performance,
but in your case map works on array but your json is an object,
change fetch like below:

```
.then((json) => setData(json.search))
```

Comment: I tried this, it's showing an error undefined

Comment: can you log json in it and comment here
like: (json)=>{console.log(json)}